# keeping an object alive in C#

Tags: c#

I have a `class X` with large size field member `y` (in terms of memory) that is declared as static member, I noticed that each time I instantiate an object of `X`, this field get either loaded or reloaded in the memory. the underlying structure of `y` is a `dictionary<string,int>` which holds around 5000 kvs. is there a way to declare `y` as a separate explicit dictionary an keep it alive during the application life time ?

Notice that: an object of X can be disposed during runtime, so the more accurate question is : if the dictionary is declared as static member of a class, would the static member remains in memory if the the class's object got garbage collected or explicitly destroyed ?

Comment: Static members stay alive for the life of the application. How did you notice that the field gets reloaded?

Comment: How did you get to know this - `each time I instantiate an object of X, this field get either loaded or reloaded in the memory`? Static fields are initialized or loaded only once in their life time.

Comment: "I noticed that each time I instantiate an object of X, this field get either loaded or reloaded in the memory" -- Can you show us your constructor? I'm curious if you have `y = new Dictionary<string, int>() { etc..}`

Comment: yes, I have y = new Dictionary<string, int>() {kvs};

Comment: In the constructor? That would be why.. if it's a static field just do `static Dictionary<string, int> y = new Dictionary<string, int>(){ initialize it here};`, don't do it in the constructor. [Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645758(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: Ohh. Then you should be initializing static fields in-line or in a static constructor. Static constructor runs only once in its life time.

Comment: Ok guys thanks a lot for your replies, I have only small question, if the dictionary is declared as static member of a class, would the static member remains in memory if the the class's object got garbage collected or explicitly destroyed ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are reinstantiating your static field in the instance constructor of the class which is causing the reload/reinstantiation of the dictionary variable. Initialize the static field either in-line where it is declared in the class

```
static Dictionary<string, int> y = new Dictionary<string, int>() {kvs};
```

OR

in a static constructor

```
static Dictionary<string, int> y;
static myClass()
{
    y = new Dictionary<string, int>() {kvs};
}
```

Static constructor of a class or static field initializers run only once in their life-time.

Comment: I have only small question, if the dictionary is declared as static member of a class, would the static member remains in memory if the the class's object got garbage collected or explicitly destroyed ?

Comment: Yes. Static members of a class are held with a special instance of a class which is known as `Type Instance`. `Type Instance` is garbage collected only when you unload the app domain.

Comment: Yes, it would remain in the memory, because static members are part of the type definition, they are not instance (object) members

Comment: Thank you RBT for your help, and thanks to all other repliers.